# How to use jQuery to modify dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning my way around jQuery but I think this may be pretty simple:

I have 2 dropdown boxes with name and id of: `topnumber`, `bottomnumber`

Both lists contain the numbers 1-5.

What I'd like to do is use jQuery to disable or remove from `bottomnumber` any number GREATER than what they picked in top number (equal is OK).  For example if they pick 3 in `topnumber` then 4 and 5 would be removed or disabled from the `bottomnumber` list.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bxa6/1/)**

```
$(function(){
  $('#topnumber').change(function() {
     var topValue = parseInt(this.value);

     $('#bottomnumber option').attr("disabled", false).filter(function(){
        //This will make sure to select only options with value > topValue
        return (topValue < parseInt(this.value)); 
     }).attr("disabled", true);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zTCGm/)

```
$('#topNumber').change(function() {
    var num = $(this).val();
    $('#bottomNumber option').removeAttr('disabled').filter(function() {
        return Number($(this).attr('value')) >= num;
    }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This code uses [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the matched set of options to the ones which are greater than `val` and then disables all options in the matched set.

Comment: Once disabled it will not enable the options again if top number is changed, take a look at my answer.

Comment: That's correct. I could just chain an `attr` call. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the change event of each of your drop down lists, and alter the values of the other according to what a user enters.

To do this use jQuery's .[change](http://api.jquery.com/change/), e.g.

```
$("#bottomnumber").change(function() { 
$(this).val() - this will be the selected value
$("#topnumber")...do stuff to the top number one
});
```

And vice versa.

Hope that helps...not the complete code but should set you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/WYcPb/1/) is a live example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   buildBottomOptions();
});

$('#top').change(function() {
    buildBottomOptions();
});


function buildBottomOptions() {
    var value = $('#top').val();
    var options = '';

    for (i = 1; i <= value; i++)
       options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';

    $('#bottom').find('option').remove().end().append(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [:gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) lets you do this fairly easily. [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GjwzG/)

```
$("#topnumber").change(function(e) {
   // turn the value of #topnumber in a javascript integer
   var num = parseInt($(this).val());
   // :gt is zero-indexed, which means that :gt(0) will get 2,3,4,5
   // and 1 would get 3,4,5 etc, etc.., so subtract one.
   num = num - 1 
   // reset the list so that everything is active.
   $("#bottomnumber option").removeAttr('disabled');
   // disable the ones which are higher than topnumber's value
   $("#bottomnumber option:gt("+num+")").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: That's certainly worth pointing out: that the numbers have to be sequential, starting with 1 for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[id="topnumber"]').change(function () {
        var maxValue = parseInt($('select[id="topnumber"]').attr('value'));
        $(' select[id="bottomnumber"] option').attr('disabled', false).filter(function() {
            return parseInt($(this).attr('value')) > maxValue ;
        }).attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

See example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/XLUju/](http://jsfiddle.net/XLUju/9/)